# UITableView/cell query - how to get a table view like iStudiez?

Tags: ios, uitableview

How does thie iStudiez app get its table cells looking like this:

[image: iStudiez table view]

Presumably the cell content is just lots of views. But what about the Now: and Next: tags, how is that made to look like that?

Comment: I'm hoping someone answers this.  I'd like to know as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOW and NEXT are SECTIONS

Table is of type GROUPED so Sections are Grouped so have rounded corners and sub rows are grouped together

NOW/NEXT headers are custom views created in 
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

Rows are Custom TableView cells with gradient backgrounds either down in Core Graphics or png.